# @PropertySource fails to autowire required class (Spring Boot 2.3.8.RELEASE)

Tags: java, spring, azure, intellij-idea

I have the following class I plan on using to autowire an instance of a Spring class named AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:default-integration.yml")
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AADFilterManager {​​​​​​​​
    @Autowired
    private AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter aadAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Although the default-integration.yml file is well placed under /resources (no 'FileNotFoundException' is thrown), it seems like during the application start-up, Spring, for whatever reason, is not able to read it's content (or disregards it while trying to initialize aadAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter).

[image]

It throws errors related to missing properties, which do exist (if I move the properties as they are into the application.yml file - the autowiring completes successfully).

```
Field aadAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter in com.security.AADFilterManager required a bean of type 'com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter' that could not be found.
 The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'azureADStatelessAuthFilter' in 'AADAuthenticationFilterAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (azure.activedirectory.client-id) did not find property 'client-id'
```

My default-integration file:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: B
            client-secret: C
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: A
    client-id: B
    client-secret: C
    session-stateless: true
    app-id-uri: D
    user-group:
      allowed-groups: Users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I ran into exactly this issue, this is how I resolved it.

First, you need to define a YamlPropertySourceFactory class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(@Nullable String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        Properties propertiesFromYaml = loadYamlIntoProperties(resource);
        String sourceName = name != null ? name : resource.getResource().getFilename();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(sourceName, propertiesFromYaml);
    }

    private Properties loadYamlIntoProperties(EncodedResource resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // for ignoreResourceNotFound
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof FileNotFoundException)
                throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getCause();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this on the beans where you want to use a yaml file as your PropertySource. For example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class, value = "classpath:datasource.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, does this factory support multiple yaml files with the same structure? I have two classes, both of them have a String taken directly from the yaml (using @Value), whenever they are autowired - the same exact value appears in both clases, I would have expected them taking the value from each file instead.

    @Value("${azure.activedirectory.app-id-uri}")
    String appIdUri;

Comment: Hi Eddie, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say. Could you please add a section to your question where you use my solution but present the new problems you are running into?